# The same ng-include works in one view but fails in another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two views: `welcome.html` and `resources.html`. Both have a

```
<ng-include src="'ui/admin/partials/header.html'"></ng-include>
```

at the very top. When it is to be displayed, `welcome.html` makes a successful XHR request for the header and displays its content. Weirdly, `resources.html` does not — no request for the header appears in the console — just a successful request for `resources.html` alone. The contents of `resources.html` are being displayed without a problem, it's the header that's missing.

The only difference between the two views is that `welcome.html` contains an `ui-sref` to the `resources.html`view. I know that link works because it does indeed take me to `resources.html`, only that the header is missing.

When I give the `ng-include` in `welcome.html` a non-existent partial for its `src` attribute, the console returns a 404. When I try the same with `resources.html`, no such error is returned, only a 200 for `resources.html`. So it appears to me that the `ng-include` in `resources.html` is not making a request for the header partial.

So how do I solve this?

Comment: how is your file structure, are those html files in the same level?

Comment: Make sure that the path of the included html is correct.

Comment: Comment 1: Indeed they are not on the same level, but I confirmed that my directory structure is not what's tripping me up by feeding the `ng-include` in `welcome.html` a `src` attribute with a non-existent URL. Predictably, the console threw a 404. No such error when I tried the same with `resources.html` — just a 200 for `resources.html` alone.
Comment 2: Of course, the path of the included file is correct. It's the same `ng-include`, after all. If it worked in `welcome.html`, it's supposed to work in `resources.html`, too.

Comment: Check the permissions of the html file, and make sure you have read access.

Comment: Are you using some resources loader ? aka `$ocLazyLoad` `requireJs` is your header controller loaded ? Add a `Console.log('header controller loaded')` in your controller to check.